# Why would it require a crane to lift a nucleus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, nuclear-physics

Citing ***D.C. Pandey's Objective Physics*** considering questions related to **IIT-JEE**, it was asked in ASSERTIONS AND REASONING why  would it require a crane to lift a small mass of nucleus.In reasoning, they had told that it requires a crane to lift a nucleus because of **heavy density of nucleus which is in order of 10^+17 kg/m^3.**
Now, my question is that lifting something up only requires work to be done against the gravity and this depends wholly on the mass.So, how does density play any role here?
Here is the image--
[image: What the question looks like!]

Comment: Their use of "Reason" seems a bit odd.  It's like saying "Warm air will rise above cooler air." Then saying the reason as "Less dense air rises".  It's not completely untrue, but there's a disconnect between cause and effect.  Their answer format seems terrible, since just citing the density isn't an actual reason to require a crane.

Comment: @JMac Only this led me to a serious confusion.They don't know to connect the dots.Still unsure about the answer.

Comment: The only reason density would matter is to define a weight. Note, it doesn't say "lifting a nucleus" it says "lifting nuclear mass of microscopic size." So, you would have to decide what microscopic size really means and use the density to define a weight. But even then, it's a bad question -- I would define "microscopic" to be something roughly 1 micron on each side. Which would be a volume of 10^(-18) and so the mass would still be less than a kilogram.

Comment: But, if you defined microscopic to be something else, like say 100 microns per side, the volume would be 10^(-12) and now it would weigh 10^5 kg. Something that would definitely need a crane.

Comment: The questions turns on two ideas. First the meaning of "microscopic"; which has a low bound on order of a micrometer for an optical instrument. Secondly the density of nuclear matter which you might reasonably take to be the density of some heavy nucleus such as lead, gold or uranium. The find the mass of a sphere one micrometer in diameter.

Comment: Solved my problem.  tpg2114 and @dmckee .However, these types of writing genres should be discouraged.

Comment: @LalaByte Might I suggest -- once you wrap your head around the idea and come up with a concrete explanation based on what we've said, go ahead and add it as an answer to your own question. Explaining things to others is a great way to learn and it helps out the site to have all questions answered.

Comment: Who questions, verifies authority? They should be more careful checking themselves. Lesson learned: even authority fallible. Hopefully mistakes like this teach the students to be skeptical, even of authority

Comment: Correct. @docscience

Answer (score 1):

radii of atomic nuclei vary between $1,75\:fm$ and $15\: fm$ (lightest to heaviest atoms), i.e we talk about order of $10^{-15}\:m$ in general. Mass density is defined as $$\rho=\frac{m}{V}A$$ where $A$ is the mass number, $m$ mass of a nucleon and $V=(4/3)\pi R^3$. So we have that $m\sim 10^{-27}\: kg$ and $V\sim 10^{-45}\: m^3$. Therefore:
$$\rho\sim 10^{45}\cdot 10^{-27}\cdot A\sim10^{18}\: kg\cdot m^{-3}$$
I believe the author thinks in the following manner. If you have an object that weighs 1 ton ($10^3\: kg$), you would probably use a crane to lift it. Suppose the object consists only of "nuclear matter". Then its volume is: $$V=\frac{m_{obj}}{\rho}\sim {10^3\cdot10^{-18}}={10^{-15}}\: m^3$$
which is approximately similar to a cube with side length $\sim 10\:\mu m$. I think this can be considered fairly microscopic.

Comment: or a ball with radius $\sim 10\:\mu m$, since you would need approximately 10^30 nucleons to get that mass, i.e $R=A^{1/3}R_0\sim 10^{10}\cdot 10^{-15}=10^{-5}\: m$

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the key point is what's the size or volume of the "microscopic size". For only one nucleus that has a diameter about $1fm=10^{-15}m$, the mass is $(10^{-15})^3\times 10^{17}=10^{-28}Kg$.